# Java - How to make a textField dimensions change based on the length of text entered?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to make the width/height of my JTextField chnage depending on the text that the user is entering.

```
JTextField tf= new JTextField(20);
    tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tf.resize(tf.getDocument().getLength(),tf.getDocument().getLength());
        }


        });
```

Is there a way to change its dimensions while text is being entered into the field, meanwhile also changing the  dimensions of the frame accordingly?

Comment: You shouldn't need to... people are used to having their text sort of scroll to the left after they type a lot. Besides you'd encounter a lot more layout issues later on.

Comment: Yeah, but there are also many examples where the textfield dynamically changes in height and also formats the entered text (for example adding returns when the current line of text reaches a certain width/length). Is there no simple way of achieving that?

Comment: Please edit your question to cite the examples mentioned and include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the frame too, scaling the frame to contain the textfield could be done by calling `pack()` after you have resized the textfield.